# Can I access restricted memory space by pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

So when I learnt about pointers, I got some crazy idea:
If I print a pointer, it gives an address in the memory, and if so, what part of the computer's memory is actually read? For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
   int a=1;
   int* ptr=&a;
   int i=0;
   while(1)
   {
      cout<<(ptr+i)<<"\t"<<*(ptr+i)<<"\n";
      i++;
   }
}
```

When I run this program (considering no errors) it gives me addresses from `&a` ++. So it loops through addresses in memory, and displays the information stored there. So my question is, which part of the memory is being read? And is it possible for me to access every single memory location (the value that is stored in each)? Can I delete (this sounds stupid as hell) files on my computer by sth like this

```
ptr=nullptr;
while(1)
{
   *(ptr+i)=0;
   i++;
}
```

I don't know whether my syntax is correct, though you get the idea. I don't dare run this on my computer...

Comment: You are not allowed to access memory you don't own.  You are also not allowed to access a pointer after it no longer points to the object/array that it pointed  to.  Anything this code does is undefined behavior.

Comment: It depends on your system.  On an archaic or embedded system with no memory protection, doing this may indeed overwrite other programs or part of the OS (usually not files since they would be on disk and not in memory, though files cached in memory could be corrupted).  On a modern desktop or server system, hardware memory protection will not permit that to happen.

Comment: @NateEldredge: A desktop OS may prevent a program from accessing storage which the process doesn't own, but processes will typically own storage beyond that which C or C++ language constructs have made available to a C or C++ program, and implementations will not generally trap accesses to such storage.

Comment: Depends on the operating system and the hardware.  On many embedded systems, there is no problem accessing addresses that are undefined.  Other platforms have hardware "fences" to prevent areas from being accessed.  Some operating systems may generate faults when you access an address outside of your program's space.  Whether or not they generate an exception, again, depends on your system; there are no requirements of notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you could do this then the "restriction" would be useless.

In the past - think: the MS-DOS and Windows 3.1 days - you could do this. And it would overwrite memory belonging to other programs, and probably crash the computer.

Modern operating systems use a technique called *virtual memory*, where the operating system controls your addresses! Whenever you access a pointer 0x12345678, the CPU looks in the *page table* for information about *page* 0x12345.

If that's a page belonging to your program, it will change the page address to what the page table says - so now it's 0xabcde678 - and get the data from that RAM chip. This allows the operating system to move pages around without your program noticing. One moment 0x12345678 means 0xabcde678, and the next moment it means 0x54321678, and you couldn't tell the difference.

If it's *not* a page belonging to your program, there will be no new address in the page table. In this case, the CPU *raises* a *page fault exception* - it calls a specific function in the operating system which deals with page faults. This function will see that there is no good reason for the page fault (because there are some good reasons). It ends your program and pops up a message box saying "This program has encountered a problem and needs to close".

Answer (score 5):

When running a C or C++ program, addresses may be divided into the following categories:

1. Those which have been made available to the C or C++ program by language constructs that report the address of const-qualified objects.
2. Those which have been made available to the C or C++ program by language constructs, but are not derived from const-qualified objects.
3. The Null address.
4. Those which to which the language implementation has been granted exclusive use by the environment, but which it has not made available to the program through language constructs.
5. Those about which the language implementation knows nothing.

The Standard imposes no requirements on what will happen if code tries to do anything with addresses of any but the first three categories, attempts to access storage at any address outside the first two, or attempts to write storage at any address that isn't of the second category.

Implementations which are designed to be suitable for low-level programming tasks, however, will define behaviors beyond those mandated by the Standard.  Most notably, such implementations will treat accesses of type #5 "in a [documented] fashion characteristic of the environment", whose behavior will be documented whenever and however the environment documents it.

If, for example, one is running a C implementation that targets a Commodore 64, for example, and one executes `*(char volatile*)0xD020 = 2;`, that will cause the screen border to turn red, because the Commodore 64 documents the effect of writing to that particular address.  The C compiler would know nothing about concepts like "screen", "border", or "red", but it wouldn't need to know about such things.  It would just execute a write to address 0xD020 and the hardware would respond by changing the value in the color-control latches that are sampled any time the raster scan is in the border region.  Such code would only be meaningful on platforms that define the effect of storing the value 2 to address 0xD020, but implementations intended for low-level programming shouldn't expect to know, and thus shouldn't care, about when such constructs would or would not be useful, since the programmer will often know more about the target environment than the compiler writer ever could.

Incidentally, the idea that UB could erase storage media may be related to the fact that on some machines like the Apple //c, or any Apple Ii-family machine with a floppy controller in slot 6 (the usual location), accessing (even reading) address 0xC0EF when a floppy drive is running (including any time within the first second or so of a floppy-drive access) will cause the drive to start overwriting data on the current track until the next time 0xC0EE is accessed.  Although most reads would have no side effects on most platforms, platforms where stray reads could have disastrous consequences are not merely theoretical.

Answer (score 3):

> If I print a pointer, it gives an address in the memory, and if so, what part of the computer's memory is actually read?

The simplest way of explaining how an executable works is, first the executable is loaded from the ROM (HHD and/or SSD) to the RAM which then the CPU executes. When you refer to a pointer of a **valid** variable, what it shows is the memory address of that variable in the RAM.

> When I run this program (considering no errors) it gives me addresses from &a ++. So it loops through addresses in memory, and displays the information stored there. So my question is, which part of the memory is being read?

It shows the memory locations which the executable *might* not own. You shouldn't access memory that your not allowed! Usually itll trigger a runtime error stating: `Access Violation Reading Location 0x...`.

> And is it possible for me to access every single memory location (the value that is stored in each)?

No, you cant and you shouldn't. That's because the OS wont allow you to read memory which you don't own, and its a security threat. If you want to access a block of memory, allocate it first.

> Can I delete (this sounds stupid as hell) files on my computer by sth like this

No, files are stored in the ROM while as what you point to in that pointer is in RAM.

> I don't dare run this on my computer...

Yes you shouldn't and you cant because the OS might stop you from doing it (some operating systems might not enforce it tightly ie: Embedded systems).

Comment: In fact on anything remotely modern, the pointer doesn't point to memory you don't own. The pointer points nowhere as the page table lookup says that page doesn't exist.

Comment: Wait a minute... So if a pointer is pointing to an address in RAM, then there is no possible threat for my OS. If I read RAM, I'm not accessing HD, so I don't manipulate with permanent storage

Comment: @Mr.Stark135 *So if a pointer is pointing to an address in RAM, then there is no possible threat for my OS* It *might* not affect the RAM but it could interfere with other applications. Modern operating systems prevent you from doing it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Code is an abstract description of what the program should do once compiled. The basis for this abstract description is the C++ language as specified in the standard. Nothing in the standard specifies what it means to take an arbitrary pointer, increment it and then dereference it (unless all this happens inside an array). The official term is: Undefined behavior. If you compile code with undefined behavior, anything can happen. It is a bit like forcing someone to translate "foofoo moomoo" from English to a different language.

In the presence of undefined behavior, we can use what we know about the well defined parts of C++ and try to extrapolate what happens when you compile and run code that has undefined behavior. However, that's futile, because sometimes compilers can detect UB and act accordingly. If you ask a compiler to compile your code, in the resulting executable there need not be any pointer increment at all (because your pointer increments and subsequent dereferences are undefined).

If you still want to know what the resulting executable actually does, you need to study the output of the compiler, eg as assembly. But don't be surprised by widely differing results depending on compiler, its version and settings when the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: I like the translation analogy but 463035818 is still not a prime...

Comment: "foofoo moomoo" would be "blubblub muhmuh" in German

Comment: @Joshua nah it is "Ich werde diese Schallplatte nicht kaufen. Sie ist zerkratzt." definitely!

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I liked the idea but I am a bit disappointed that I didnt manage to include a monty python reference from the start

Answer (score 0):

In a general sense, dynamically allocated space usually placed in a program segment known as the heap or the free store. You must use the `new` keyword to let the computer allocate memory from that heap space.

When you run out of heap space, for example when you keep dynamically allocating new pointers but do not delete the unused pointers, errors like this could happen `std::bad_alloc`

On the other hand, if you try to access a memory that is not dynamically allocated. `Segmentation Fault` is almost definitely happening.
A very simple example would be when you try to read an out-of-bound array element. Since C++ does not have bound checking. You could easily venture out into the danger zone and barred from illegal memory access. In your case, trying to access a memory that is next to, but not allocated to, your assigned memory would cause a segmentation fault. Of course, you can definitely print the memory. But accessing the memory and actually changing its content is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your program in Visual Studio Community 2019. There are many memory positions printed but after a few seconds, an exception is thrown: read access violation.
All variables in your program are created on the stack. The first iteration of the loop shows the contents of variable 'a' (value 1), which is on the stack, but next iterations shows contents of memory that also belong to the stack of your program. Finally, a memory position out of the stack is tried to be read, so the exception is thrown.
Back in the days of MS-DOS, there would not have been any problem when trying to read memory beyond the stack of your program, because the operating system did not protect memory locations.

When I try to write memory locations with '*(ptr + i) = 0;' instead of reading them, what is thrown is a write access violation exception. In the days of MS-DOS, this would have provoked overwriting memory locations beyond the program stack and this would have affected to other running programs, probably the computer would have hanged and you would have had to restart it, which it was common when mistakes were made when working with pointers.